# Drupal node selector strategy?

Tags: drupal, cck

I've got a content type called "contact". One user can create hundreds of contacts. I need another list of contacts stored somewhere else. Options:

1. Use a view
2. Create a new content type called "contacts" (with an s) and add a selector or node reference so you can just tick the nodes you like.

2 sounds like the best option to me, but I want to be able to have a better way of physically selecting the contact, as a user can have hundreds and maybe even thousands of contacts. So, my question really boils down to:

1. What's the nicest way (using drupal) that I can allow a user to select several nodes (but technically one at a time)
2. Is there a way to add a "SELECT ALL" checkbox to a normal select list cck in drupal?

Comment: I have seen multiple node reference selectors working with the ajax auto select. Don't have the code with me to provide answer at the moment but that may be what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiselect) module solved my problem. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... defines a widget to be used with CCK fields. It allows the user to select multiple items in an easy way. It consists of two lists, one of all available items, the other of selected items. The user can select an item by moving it from the unselected list to the selected list. This module relies on the built-in jQuery features of Drupal and does not require any additional modules other than the CCK module set (Drupal 7 version has no dependencies).